# How can I show my changelog.md file info in Google Consul and App Store?

Tags: flutter, app-store, google-play-console, changelog, codemagic

I want to show my changelogs in Google Consul and App Store with every new app version but can't find any way to do it with Codemagic Flutter workflow editor. Can anyone say how can I do it?

I can't find any working solution so I hope someone can help me with this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find one solution.I created release_notes.json and put my changes in that file after build, all changes shown in App Store and Play store.

Answer (score 0):

In apps this is called "what's new" section, and you can do it with codemagic.

In Apple app store the user can see "what's new" for all versions, but in Google play every version have it's own "what's new".

If you looking for this in consoles, you have to submit the build first to TestFlight and fill the "what's new" or version description, then rlease the test flight version, your change log will be in TestFlight section. In Google play console you have submit the build to internal testing first and fill what's new with what you want.